# Reflection in file of replacing a particular string

Tags: java, string, file

I have a text file as:

```
my name is abhi
my name is khan
my name is koushik
```

Now I want to replace "khan" by "viswajit".I have written a code for it. My expected output is:

```
my name is abhi
my name is viswajit
my name is koushik
```

My code actually is replacing "khan"by "Viswajit". But tranketing few letters of next line.
I am getting O/P as:

```
my name is abhi
my name is viswajit
name is koushik.
```

The "my" word is missing in the last line.
Please check it and give me some idea.
Here is my code:

```
public static void replaceStringInFile(String fileName, String match, String replacingString){
        try {
        File file = new File(fileName);

        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        long pointer = raf.getFilePointer();
        String lineData = "";

        while((lineData =raf.readLine()) != null){
        pointer = raf.getFilePointer() - lineData.length()-2;
        if(lineData.indexOf(match) > 0){

            lineData = lineData.replace(match, replacingString+"\n");
            raf.seek(pointer);
            raf.writeBytes(lineData);
```

Comment: you could probably just read the entire file into a string, do a string.replace and write the replaced string back. or is it a huge file you are reading and are worried about memory?

Answer (score 1):

You are not inserting the additional text, you are over-writing.

If you want to insert text, there is no short cut to re-writing the rest of the file.

As such it may not be worth using RandomAccessFile as this is likely to be more complicated than useful. I would just use BufferedReader and PrintWriter to a copy of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using an object of `RandomAccessFile` when you are using a text file. Like Peter Lawrey says, I would suggest you to use a `BufferedReader` object to read the file and `PrintWriter`, instead.

EDIT:
I checked your code on my machine, and it's working well for me, but with this edit (`lineData.length()-2` must be `lineData.length()-1)`:

```
while((lineData =raf.readLine()) != null){
                pointer = raf.getFilePointer() - lineData.length()-1;
                if(lineData.indexOf(match) > 0){

                    lineData = lineData.replace(match, replacingString+"\n");
                    raf.seek(pointer);
                    raf.writeBytes(lineData);
                }
            }
```

However, try this code, it does the same thing but with `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter` objects, creating a new file called `the_new_file_with_replacing.txt`:

```
public static void replaceStringInFile(String fileName, String match, String replacingString){
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("the_new_file_with_replacing.txt"));

            String lineData = "";

            while((lineData = br.readLine()) != null){

                                        pw.println(lineData.replaceAll(match,replacingString));
                }
            file.close();
            br.close();
            pw.close();

            }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand is , When you are writing back, you are overwriting bytes.

check `khan` is a 4 letter word and `viswajit` is 7 letters. While you replace successive 3 bytes are also replaced. ie, you will loose a `'my'` and newline char.

Consider this and manipulate your action.

Comment: as Peter said, if u want to update means, just re-write rest of file. However you can consider other means like deleting the Whole line, and then append the new String to file.?